# Clicking SVG triggers function in page code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, svg, click, code-behind

Short question here: I have a SVG chart with nodes. Is there a way to be able to have clicking the SVG trigger a function in the page code behind? Specifically, have it be able to tell which node in the chart was clicked. I've noticed that the asp controls have this type of functionality built in, but not the more generic html components.

Comment: Add onclick to the nodes presumably per http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-svgint/index.html

Comment: Nope, that's not it. As far as I can tell onclick triggers javascript events, not events in the code-behind. I'm looking for more than just hyperlinks. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, today I got a solution to work. I will share here for anyone else looking.

My click-event trigger is an asp:ImageMap that has been placed over the SVG using CSS z-index.

Before displaying the SVG, the code-behind in the Page_Load function takes the SVG and parses it into XML so I can read/modify it like an XML document. First the program checks the 'g' element for any transformations and saves the offset to use when plotting coordinates. Then, the program looks at each shape (rect, circle, etc) element in the XML and pulls the x,y coordinates from the shape and creates a corresponding ImageMap HotSpot and adds it to the ImageMap.

Whew!